# C# windows mobile 6 application to windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-mobile, porting

I have a Windows Mobile 6 application, written in C# and I want to port it to Windows Phone 7.

What modifications do I have to do to the original application? Do I have to modify only the user interface or are there any other things I need to modify in the backgroung code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can not use native API in Windows Phone 7 applications.
2. You should recompile your dlls from wp7 environment.
3. UI should be re-written with XAML.
4. All interaction with network should be acync.
5. WebBrowser is different from WinMobile6 one.
6. You can not use sockets (should wait for Mango update).

Answer (score 2):

It is likely you will need to make a decent number of changes. The framework changed from .NET Compact Framework 3.5 to Silverlight Phone Edition, aka almost-but-not-quite Silverlight 3. And the guidelines for submission to the app store are much stricter in terms of user experience, e.g. time taken to load the app, behavior of background processing, etc.